# How do I JSON.parse an array in a Zapier Trigger?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, polling, zapier

I am trying to JSON.parse the array **"data."** I need to be able to pass the array as the root.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "name",
      "id": "123"
    }
  ]
}
```

The response should look like this containing only objects. Zapier doesn't seem to work well with arrays.

```
{
      "type": "name",
      "id": "123"
}
```

Shouldn't I be able to use a simple script to get the job done?

---

EDIT:

Essentially, you're going to want to override the `post_poll` method (https://zapier.com/developer/documentation/v2/scripting/#polling) in scripting so you can intercept the response of the API. After that, you just need to return a new object with the values you want. Instead of returning: {"data":[ {...}, {...}, ]}, you just need to return the value of data. Something like:

```
xyz_post_poll: function(bundle){
  var response = JSON.parse(bundle.response.content);
  return response.data || [];
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Zapier, are you essentially asking for a function that starts with your json and returns that object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use a simple script, Javascript or Python. Click the **+** in between your existing Trigger and Action, and add an Action, choosing Code by Zapier as the app. Assuming your JSON is the output of your Trigger:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "name",
      "id": "123"
    }
  ]
}
```

Code by Zapier would present you with these options:

[Setup Code by Zapier Run Javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYpiT.png)

If the array of objects `data` has more than one element, then Zapier presents all values for the property `type` in those objects as an array labelled ***Data Type*** and all values for property `id` as an array labelled ***Data ID***.  If you choose `type` and `id` as the property names for the `input` object to be passed to the Code app, then the Javascript object your code gets is this:

```
input = {
 type: [ "name", "name2", "name3" ],
 id: [ "123", "456", "789" ]
};
```

Your code can then transform the data any way you want, before passing to the next Action.

[Code by Zapier](https://zapier.com/help/code/),

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11879934)

Comment: Edited original post to do just that. Thanks for the constructive advice.

Answer (score 6):

I found that I needed to call `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` in order to get this to work. Assume that my input gets putted in Zapier as (key,value) where the key = data and the value is:

```
[{"type": "name", "id":"123"}, {"type": "name2", "id":"456"}, 
  {"type": "name3", "id":"789" }]
```

My code:

```
output = {};

var obj = JSON.parse(input.data);

for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
   output["myObject"+i] = JSON.stringify(obj[i]);
}
```

The output generated is:

```
myObject0: {"type":"name", "id":"123"}
myObject1: {"type":"name2", "id":"456"}
myObject2: {"type":"name3", "id":"789"}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about parsing it uses Zapier's Code By Zapier JavaScript engine, then here's what you do:

Zapier returns whatever object you tell it to, so assuming you use their standard name for `input`, here's what you do:

```
output = {};

for (var i = 0; i < input["data"].length; i++) {
  output["myObject"+str(i)] = input.data[i];
}
```

This should return an object called `output` that looks as follows:

```
"output" : {
    "myObject0" : {  
      "type": "name",
      "id": "123"
    },
    "myObject1" : {
      "type" : "name",
      "id": "124"
    }
}
```