# Zapier API Code assistance - extract data from JSON

Tags: javascript, python, json, api, zapier

I am trying to use a JSON response in a Zapier response.  The data looks like this:
[image: JSON Result]

I'm trying to use the Induction and Site Suitability href value in a Zap, however, when I try to use this in Zapier, Zapier gives me this:
[image: Zapier Selection]

I was going to use a find of some sorts to find Induction and Site Suitability and then return the href after that, but because of the formatting, I can't do that.  Does anyone know how I can do this with Formatter or Code (Python/Javascript) or something else in Zapier?

Thank you

Luke

Here is the API result in code:

```
{
"competencies": [
    {
        "competency": {
            "name": "Forklift Operator Permit",
            "href": "https://link/22059"
        },
        "status": {
            "value": "Active",
            "type": "active"
        },
        "expiryWarning": "2021-04-15T13:59:00Z",
        "expiry": "2021-04-30T13:59:00Z",
        "disabled": false,
        "href": "https://link/1b1594d738"
    },
    {
        "competency": {
            "name": "Induction and Site Suitability",
            "href": "https://link/24033"
        },
        "status": {
            "value": "Active",
            "type": "active"
        },
        "expiryWarning": "2021-04-15T13:59:00Z",
        "expiry": "2021-04-30T13:59:00Z",
        "disabled": false,
        "href": "https://link/8e26b5ea4bbc800e"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: 1) please upload text and not images. 2) what did you try so far?

Comment: I've tried basically all of the Zapier formatting options I could find.  I also tried a few Zapier code examples I found online (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36381029/how-do-i-json-parse-an-array-in-a-zapier-trigger) but I couldn't get these to work.

Comment: can you be more explicit about what output you want? It's likely possible with code, but it's unclear what data you're trying to pull out (or not)